# Only view own function calls in Sentry (self-hosted) NodeJs Profiling

Tags: node.js, nestjs, profiling, sentry

I recently upgraded to the latest self-hosted version of Sentry.
It newly enables "Profiling" and provides an incredible detailed few into the performance of our NodeJS (NestJs framework) application. Too detailed.
Screenshot 1 shows all recorded function calls and I am unable to find a view, where it only shows me the calls I have actual control over, so the methods I implemented.

The "Application Frames" tab only shows "emit" and other calls that I do not do myself (Screenshot 2).

Is there a way to configure Profiling (either in the UI or when sending the data from my NestJS application) so that it only shows the method calls I implemented?

[image: Sample screenshot of Profiling view]

[image: Sample screenshoft of Application Frames]